# Solve inequalities

Tags: inequalities, findinstance

I use FindInstance to find a set of real parameters to satisfy the following inequality

$-3 c_{11}-k_4^2-k_7^2-k_9^2>0$,

$$
-4 \alpha^6+84 \alpha^5-721 \alpha^4+3228 \alpha^3-7924 \alpha^2+10080 \alpha +16\alpha^3 k_1 k_4-16 \alpha^3 k_2 k_4-80\alpha^2 k_4^2-168 \alpha^2 k_1 k_4+168\alpha^2 k_2 k_4+496 \alpha  k_4^2+560\alpha  k_1 k_4-560 \alpha  k_2 k_4-64 k_1^2k_4^2-96 k_2^2 k_4^2+64 k_1 k_2 k_4^2-672k_4^2-64 k_4^2 k_5^2-576 k_1 k_4+576 k_2k_4-5184>0,
$$

$$
-\alpha^8+26 \alpha^7-293 \alpha^6+1868\alpha^5-7364 \alpha^4+18368 \alpha^3-28288 \alpha^2+24576 \alpha +56 \alpha^4 c_{11}-728 \alpha^3 c_{11}+3472 \alpha^2 c_{11}-7168 \alpha  c_{11}+896 c_{11} k_1k_4+896 c_{11} k_5 k_7-784 c_{11}^2+5376c_{11}+40 \alpha^4 k_9^2-32 \alpha^4 k_1k_4-32 \alpha^4 k_5 k_7-520 \alpha^3k_9^2+416 \alpha^3 k_1 k_4+416 \alpha^3k_5 k_7+2480 \alpha^2 k_9^2-1984 \alpha^2k_1 k_4-1984 \alpha^2 k_5 k_7-5120 \alpha k_9^2+4096 \alpha  k_1 k_4+4096 \alpha  k_5k_7-256 k_1^2 k_4^2-256 k_5^2 k_7^2+640 k_1k_4 k_9^2-128 k_2 k_4 k_9^2+640 k_5 k_7k_9^2+3840 k_9^2-3072 k_1 k_4-512 k_1 k_4 k_5 k_7-3072 k_5 k_7-9216>0.
$$

However, I didn't get any answer from Mathematica. Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

My code:

```
FindInstance[-5184 + 10080*α - 7924*α^2 + 
    3228*α^3 - 721*α^4 + 84*α^5 - 4*α^6 - 
    576*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    560*α*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    168*α^2*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    16*α^3*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    576*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    560*α*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    168*α^2*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    16*α^3*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    672*Subscript[k, 4]^2 + 496*α*Subscript[k, 4]^2 - 
    80*α^2*Subscript[k, 4]^2 - 
    64*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 4]^2 + 
    64*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4]^2 - 
    96*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 4]^2 - 
    64*Subscript[k, 4]^2*Subscript[k, 5]^2 > 
   0 && -9216 + 24576*α - 28288*α^2 + 
    18368*α^3 - 7364*α^4 + 1868*α^5 - 
    293*α^6 + 26*α^7 - α^8 + 
    5376*Subscript[c, 11] - 7168*α*Subscript[c, 11] + 
    3472*α^2*Subscript[c, 11] - 
    728*α^3*Subscript[c, 11] + 
    56*α^4*Subscript[c, 11] - 784*Subscript[c, 11]^2 - 
    3072*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    4096*α*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    1984*α^2*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    416*α^3*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    32*α^4*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] + 
    896*Subscript[c, 11]*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4] - 
    256*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 4]^2 - 
    3072*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] + 
    4096*α*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] - 
    1984*α^2*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] + 
    416*α^3*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] - 
    32*α^4*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] + 
    896*Subscript[c, 11]*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7] - 
    512*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4]*Subscript[k, 5]*
     Subscript[k, 7] - 256*Subscript[k, 5]^2*Subscript[k, 7]^2 + 
    3840*Subscript[k, 9]^2 - 5120*α*Subscript[k, 9]^2 + 
    2480*α^2*Subscript[k, 9]^2 - 
    520*α^3*Subscript[k, 9]^2 + 
    40*α^4*Subscript[k, 9]^2 + 
    640*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 4]*Subscript[k, 9]^2 - 
    128*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 4]*Subscript[k, 9]^2 + 
    640*Subscript[k, 5]*Subscript[k, 7]*Subscript[k, 9]^2 > 
   0 && -3*Subscript[c, 11] - Subscript[k, 4]^2 - Subscript[k, 7]^2 - 
    Subscript[k, 9]^2 > 0, {Subscript[k, 0], Subscript[k, 1], 
  Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3], Subscript[k, 4], Subscript[k, 5], 
  Subscript[k, 6], Subscript[k, 7], Subscript[k, 8], 
  Subscript[k, 9], α, Subscript[c, 11]}]
```

Comment: These parameters are all real numbers.

Comment: Post full `Mathematica` code,what have you tried?

Comment: How to post my codes?

Comment: Convert cell to `Raw InputForm` (menu Cell | Convert To | Raw InputForm), copy and paste, format as code block.

Comment: Nobody wants to have to type in all your code, so as to try and reproduce the issue so as to diagnose it.It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the way to post code.

Answer (score 4):

Let `ineq` be your system of inequalities.  One way to solve $f(x) > 0$ is to try to minimize $(f(x) - a)^2$ for some positive value of $a$. *Mathematica's* minimizers might fail to find a minimum, but they'll return the best solution, which might be good enough.  You might need to vary the conditions, such as the `"InitialPoints"` or the `"RandomSeed"` through a number of trials to find a solution.

Here's a sample iterative process that succeeds (on the first iteration!) on the problem at hand:

```
error = 2;
seed = 0;
sol = {};
While[! TrueQ[(ineq /. sol)] &&
   seed < 100,(* max iterations *)
  seed++;
  {error, sol} =
   NMinimize[
    ineq /. And -> List /. u_ > 0 :> (u - 1)^2 // Total,
    {Subscript[k, 0], Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], 
     Subscript[k, 3], Subscript[k, 4], Subscript[k, 5], 
     Subscript[k, 6], Subscript[k, 7], Subscript[k, 8], 
     Subscript[k, 9], α, Subscript[c, 11]}, 
    Method -> {"NelderMead", "RandomSeed" -> seed}]
  ];
sol
```

> ```
> (*
> {Subscript[k, 0] -> 0.476984, Subscript[k, 1] -> 0.481225, 
>  Subscript[k, 2] -> -0.784974, Subscript[k, 3] -> -0.735787, 
>  Subscript[k, 4] -> 0.268096, Subscript[k, 5] -> 0.000246397, 
>  Subscript[k, 6] -> 0.486963, Subscript[k, 7] -> -0.0000137351, 
>  Subscript[k, 8] -> -0.581396, 
>  Subscript[k, 9] -> -0.588124, α -> 3.39698, 
>  Subscript[c, 11] -> -0.144035}
> *)
> ```

```
ineq /. sol
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

Comment: Yes, your parameters satisfy the three inequalities!

Comment: When I use the code: ineq = {ineq 1, ineq 2, ineq 3}, "ineq /. sol" returns "{False, True, True}".

Comment: When I use the code: ineq = {ineq 1 && ineq 2 && ineq 3}, the code (your code) "error...sol" returns "{}".

Comment: I believe the problem is the way I input "ineq". How do you input the three inequalities as "ineq"?

Comment: I also have another similar problem. Could you please take a loot at it? Thank you! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227808/use-findinstance-for-15-equations

Comment: I set `ineq` equal to the unchanged first argument in `FindInstance`, with `&&` (`And`) and without `{`, `}` (no `List`).

Comment: Thanks!Now I can use my Mac to produce the same result.